# Performance improve almost linearly increasing GOMAXPROCS from 1 to 4 but then are sort of flat

Tags: go

I am working on a machine with 8 cores (a Mac with a "2,8 GHz Intel Core i7" processor), as I can see running `fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU())`.

I have implemented a very simple *workers pool model* to process concurrently some requests coming to the pool. The type of process is "CPU intensive" and I would like to have a feeling about how much performance improve when giving GO more cores.

So the code is the following

```
func Run(poolSize int, workSize int, loopSize int, maxCores int) {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(maxCores)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(poolSize)
    defer wg.Wait()

    // this is the channel where we write the requests for work to be performed by the pool
    workStream := make(chan int)

    // cpuIntensiveWork simulates an CPU intensive process
    var cpuIntensiveWork = func(input int) {
        res := input
        for i := 0; i < loopSize; i++ {
            res = res + i
        }
    }

    // worker is the function that gets fired by the pool
    worker := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, workStream chan int, id int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for req := range workStream {
            cpuIntensiveWork(req)
        }
    }

    // launch the goroutines of the pool
    for i := 0; i < poolSize; i++ {
        go worker(&wg, workStream, i)
    }

    // feed the workStream until the end and then close the channel
    for workItemNo := 0; workItemNo < workSize; workItemNo++ {
        workStream <- workItemNo
    }
    close(workStream)
}
```

and the benchmarks are these

```
var numberOfWorkers = 100
var numberOfRequests = 1000
var loopSize = 100000

func Benchmark_1Core(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Run(numberOfWorkers, numberOfRequests, loopSize, 1)
    }
}
func Benchmark_2Cores(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Run(numberOfWorkers, numberOfRequests, loopSize, 2)
    }
}
func Benchmark_4Cores(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Run(numberOfWorkers, numberOfRequests, loopSize, 4)
    }
}
func Benchmark_8Cores(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Run(numberOfWorkers, numberOfRequests, loopSize, 8)
    }
}
```

Running the benchmarks I have noticed that the performance increases almost linearly moving from 1 Core to 2 Cores to 4 Cores. But the difference in performance that I get moving from 4 Cores to 8 Cores is very much limited.

Is this an expected behavior? If so, which is the underlying reason?

Comment: Have you checked to see what other processes are using CPU at the same time?

Comment: the machine is basically idle, nothing special running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With multiple cores things can get interesting. The most likely explanation is that you don't have eight cores, but four cores with hyperthreading which will give you much less of a speedup - sometimes none at all.

Another *possible* explanation to check is that each thread uses huge amounts of memory, and you run out of cache memory. Or you reach the point where memory bandwidth is saturated, and at that point no number of processors is going to help you.

Comment: I think that "four cores with hyperthreading" is the explanation. Thanks